# SQL Comparar si dos fechas son iguales

Tags: java, mysql, sql

me encuentro haciendo un programita en el cual necesitocomparar una fecha que tengo almacenada en mi BD (Mysql/PhpMyAdmin) con otra que le doy yo mediante una interfaz, para que si , ambas coinciden y coincida un numero de empleado se elimine el registro. Actualmente tengo esto `DELETE FROM " + NOMBRE_TABLA_HORARIOS + " WHERE numeroEmpleado = " + codigoTrabajador + " AND fecha = '" + fecha + "';";`.......

La fecha que recojo por la interfaz la estoy casteando mediante `java.sql.Date.valueOf(dpFechaEliminarHorario.getValue())`, y el resultado que me da del casteo, por ejemplo siendo el dia de hoy seria `2019-04-20` , por lo cual el formato seria el corrector creo. El programa no me arroja ningun error al ejecutar la consulta, solamente que no hace nada.

Otra de las dudas seria como comparar una fecha almacenada en la BD con la fecha del dia actual.
Gracias y un saludo.

Comment: ¿Desde qué lenguaje construyes esta query? ¿Python? Sería interesante que pusieras su etiqueta en la pregunta.

Comment: No hay inconveniente en que amplíes la pregunta detallándola más pero, si eliminas parte de ésta, parece que la respuesta es incorrecta, cuando respondía a lo que preguntabas cuando la publicaste por primera vez. Por favor, añade lo que preguntabas sobre la fecha actual. Con respecto a tu variable `fecha`, ¿has intentado mostrar su valor en pantalla para asegurarte de que almacena el dato en el formato correcto?

Answer (score 2):

Puedes hacer lo mismo que has hecho, pero utilizando la función `NOW()` y quedándote únicamente con la fecha sin tener en cuenta la hora, utilizando `DATE()`. Te quedaría algo así:

```
DELETE FROM " + NOMBRE_TABLA_HORARIOS + " 
   WHERE numeroEmpleado = " + codigoTrabajador + " 
   AND fecha = DATE(NOW());";
```

Comment: Genial, he resuelto el problema al comparar con la fecha actual, pero aun no puedo eliminar si comparo entre una fecha que doy yo y la que tengo en la BD. He probado esta opcion ' "DELETE FROM " + NOMBRE_TABLA_HORARIOS + " WHERE numeroEmpleado = " + codigoTrabajador + " AND fecha = DATE(" + fecha + ");";' y nada.

Comment: ¿En qué formato estás guardando la fecha en la variable `fecha`? ¿yyyy-mm-dd?

Comment: Si, con ese formato.

Comment: Si `fecha` ya está en ese formato, no necesitas `DATE()`. En cualquier caso haz un `print(fecha)` para asegurarte de que está bien escrita. Modifica tu pregunta e incluye el mensaje de error que estás recibiendo.

Comment: No se como , pero el problema se ha solucionado solo, muchas gracias por la ayuda aportada!

Comment: Por favor, indícanos si esta respuesta ha aclarado tu duda y de qué forma podemos ampliarla para que también pueda ayudar a otras personas en tu misma situación. Has hecho un esfuerzo planteando la pregunta, no lo dejemos a medio camino. [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)

Comment: La repuesta ha sido de mucha ayuda, he resuelto ambos problemas.